# kubectl get node getting unable to connect to the server

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, minikube

The Google cloud SDK console showing "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." below error when I'm trying to run kubectl commands

[click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbIYl.png)

Comment: Where is your Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: That error means that you do not have a valid kubeconfig file. Please follow this steps (gcloud container clusters get-credentials
)[https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials] to get your kubeconfig file. Confirm with us if the error persist.

Comment: Is your master private?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that your `kubeconfig` is not correct.

In order to use connect to cluster you can run:

```
gcloud container clusters list
```

to get the name of your cluster and then run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name>
```

to generate `kubeconfig` for chosen cluster.